# AWS cli sync filenames with date newer than two years

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I have multiple files in my S3 bucket and I need a crontab to sync only files which newer than 2 years.
I have a lot of files with `'+%y%m%d'` format and postfix with number

```
20170717-0
20210110-1
```

I don't have any idea how to sync with this condition `$(date --date='<=2 year ago' '+%Y%m%d')`.

Also I know about --include and --exclude.
And don't want to use workaround with delete files with find and mtime.

Comment: Do the files have a `LastModified` date of 2 years ago, or are you simply wanting to base it on the filename?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein They can be modified any day and yes, I want base it on the filename

Comment: You can't really use the `aws s3 sync` command because it works on wildcards (eg `2021*`), not comparisons. You would like need to sync for every desired year (`2021*`) or month (`202101*`) by providing an `--include` for each one.

Comment: Yeah, I've pointed this, but If i sync 2020* i will get files older than 2 years, so I don't want them to sync. If i will provide cycle with dates in range of 2 years I will get a lot of calls to aws cli, so i dont want it too.
I just need a script or exclude+include option with syncing all files that has dates in filenames with not older than 2 years ago

Comment: Then do it by month, or even by day. There is no sub-command in the `sync` command that will do exactly as you request. You'll need to be specific in `--include` paths you provide.